# Combining lots of similar actions in a html "onclick" event

Tags: javascript, html, events, onclick

I need to make a button in a page that toggles visibility of some table rows. It's already working well, but the "onclick" event inside the "a" tag is filled with a lot of redundant information, i want to make it cleaner. The code i'm using (and it's working well) is like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function toggle_visibleid(id) {
       var e = document.getElementById(id);
       if(e.style.display == 'none')
          e.style.display = 'table-row';
       else
          e.style.display = 'none';
    }
</script>

<a href="#" onclick=
 "toggle_visibleid('cena1');
  toggle_visibleid('cena2');
  toggle_visibleid('cena3');
  toggle_visibleid('cena4');
  toggle_visibleid('cena5');
  toggle_visibleid('cena6');
  toggle_visibleid('cena7');
  toggle_visibleid('cena8');
  toggle_visibleid('cena9');
  toggle_visibleid('cena14');
  toggle_visibleid('cena15');
  toggle_visibleid('cena16');
  toggle_visibleid('cena17');
  toggle_visibleid('cena18');
  toggle_visibleid('cena19');
  toggle_visibleid('cena20');
  toggle_visibleid('cena21');
  toggle_visibleid('cena22');
  toggle_visibleid('cena23');">Gravações</a>
```

Is there a way to make it smaller? Like:

```
<a href="#" onclick="toggle_visibleid('cena1' 'cena2' 'cena3' 'cena4' 'cena5' 'cena6' 'cena7' 'cena8' 'cena9' 'cena14' 'cena15' 'cena16' 'cena17' 'cena18' 'cena19' 'cena20' 'cena21' 'cena22' 'cena23');">Gravações</a>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Is there a pattern which "cena" should be toggled? The best is always to avoid inline script and call those function from javascript event handler

Comment: … and what is `cena*` - a class, an id or something else entirely?

Comment: Do you have many `<a>` tags with same behaviour?

Comment: You should be using a CSS class name to do this. Forget individual IDs.

Comment: @sergio and @insertusernamehere cena** is an id that is applied to a `<tr>` tag. I have 6 `<a>` with similar behaviours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a function that takes an array of ids and then iterates through the ids calling your existing toggle_visibledid function each time.

```
<a href="#" onclick="toggleVisibleIds(['cena1', 'cena2', 'cena3', 'cena4', 'cena5', 'cena6', 'cena7', 'cena8', 'cena9', 'cena14', 'cena15', 'cena16', 'cena17', 'cena18','cena19', 'cena20','cena21','cena22','cena23']);">Gravações</a> 

   function toggleVisibleIds(ids){
        for(var i = 0, id; id = ids[i++];){
            toggle_visibleid(id);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest

- using a 'real' event listener
- setting up a loop or whatever in order to shorten your pattern

```
var link = document.getElementById("link"); // get your <a> tag somehow
link.addEventListener("click", function () {
  var prefix = "cena";

  // loop 1-9 and 14-23
  for (var i=1; i<=9; i++) {
    toggle_visibleid(prefix + i);
  }

  for (var i=14; i<=23; i++) {
    toggle_visibleid(prefix + i);
  }
});
```

If your *cena* IDs represent element IDs, I'd advise using classes intead, for example:

```
<tag id="cena1" class="myCena">
<tag id="cena2" class="myCena">
...
```

This would allow a cleaner code:

```
link.addEventListener("click", function () {
  var cenaElements = document.querySelectorAll(".myCena");
  for (var i=0, len=cenaElements.length; i<len; i++) {
    toogle_visible(cenaElements.get(i));
  }
});
```

Note that you have to rewrite your `toggle_visible(id)` function.

Answer (score 1):

define a function

```
function customToggleVisibleId(list) {
     for(var i=0; i<list.length; i++) {
          toggle_visibleid(list[i]);
     }
}
```

then you can

```
<a href="#" onclick="customToggleVisibleId(['cena1' 'cena2' 'cena3'])">
```

Edit: For maximum performance:

```
function customToggleVisibleId() {
     var i=arguments.length;
     while(i--) {
          toggle_visibleid(arguments[i]);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function toggle_multiple_visible() {
    for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        toggle_visibleid(arguments[i]);
    }
}
```

Then use:

```
onclick="toggle_multiple_visible('cena1', 'cena2', ...);"
```

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using jQuery to match the `cena**` elements. To achieve this, you might want to re-think how you are identifying them. Perhaps use a class that is applied to all of these elements?

You can then use the jQuery [each](http://api.jquery.com/each/) function to invoke some action on each matching element.

Answer (score 0):

Store the elements to be toggled in an array, then use a function to loop through the array to hide them.  This could be simplified if there is some standard pattern for the naming of these "cena" elements.

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
var cenaArray = ['cena1', 'cena2', 'cena3', 'cena4', 'cena5', 'cena6', 'cena7', 'cena8', 'cena9', 'cena14', 'cena15', 'cena16', 'cena17', 'cena18', 'cena19', 'cena20', 'cena21', 'cena22', 'cena23'];

function toggleAll() {
  for(var i=0; i<cenaArray.length; i++)
  {
      toggle_visibleid( cenaArray[i] );
  }
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<a href="#" onclick="toggleAll()">Gravações</a>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" onclick="toggleCena()">Gravações</a>
```

**Script**

```
function toggleCena(){
    for(i=1; i<24; i++){
        tempid="cena"+i;
        toggle_visibleid(tempid);
    }
}
```

I have no idea what `toggle_visibleid` does but try this